# Size allocated for datatypes

Tags: mysql

If I set varchar (250) say on charset latin1 when I add a value say 'abc' characters does it means that the data allocated for it is 251bytes or 4bytes?  Would it be the same way for other data types? Please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a varchar(250) and you add 'abc' then 3 bytes/characters are allocated.
If you had user char(250) then 250 bytes/characters would have been allocated.

Note that for VARCHAR a minimal storage overhead is used internally to represent the datatype.

Comment: So can I consider 4 bytes for varchar will be allocated in real. And 251 if it were to be char?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL manual has a whole [chapter on storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html).

A `VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL` takes one byte to store the length *n*, and *n* bytes to store the actual string. So a column holding a value `'abc'` will account for 4 bytes. In a `VARCHAR(250) NULL`, the nullity takes one bit, and a `NULL` value won't take anything else. A non-null value takes that bit, one byte for length and *n* bytes for data. *Needing a bit* here means that several nullable columns share one or more bytes to record their nullity.

Other variable length data types are similar. BLOB and TEXT types of the various sizes may have more than a single byte for length, but otherwise work pretty much the same. Numeric types as well as the fixed-length `CHAR` types have fixed memory requirements. I think I the `CHAR` will omit the length byte, as its content is padded with spaces to that fixed length.

Indices might increase the memory requirements. Multy-byte character sets (including UTF-8) might increase the memory requirements, so the above statements will only hold if your table was created for latin1 or similar.